# Large file include in build or use axios in runtime

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-leaflet

I have a couple large files (50-300MB) that I want to display on my website. These are GeoJSON files that I currently download to a local file and include in my build.
However, I can also have the app pull that same data from a public API at runtime via Axios to achieve the same goal. My question is what the best practice is in this situation? Any pros/cons (besides relying on public api for endpoint and service changes)